# Call method in object with other method in same object

Tags: javascript, object, methods

I need `validateText` function to call `modalFunc`. How can I do that?

```
function geoAlert(lodash) {

    var me = this;

    return {
        modalFunc: function(text) {
            alert(text);
        },
        validateText: function() {
            modalFunc("hello")
        }
    }
}
```

When I run:

`geoAlert.validateText();` I will get this error:

`ReferenceError: modalFunc is not defined`

Using `me.modalFunc("hello")` does not work too. Please help and thanks in advance.

Comment: It depends on how `validateText` is called. Seems like you mostly just need to learn about how `this` works in JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a named function:

```
function geoAlert(lodash) {

    function modalFunc(text) {
      alert(text);
    }

    return {
        modalFunc: modalFunc,
        validateText: function() {
            modalFunc("hello")
        }
    }
}
```

Then doesn't matter how `validateText` is called. But you should still [learn about `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this), since you attempted something with `var me = this;` which probably doesn't do what you want anyway.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're trying to use a revealing module pattern; returning an object that effectively provides methods. For this to work you need to execute your main function as follows (note the '()' at the end meaning it will be immediately invoked):

```
var geoAlert = function(lodash) {

    return {
      modalFunc: function(text) {
            alert(text);
      },
      validateText: function() {
        this.modalFunc("hello")
      }
    };
}();


geoAlert.validateText('Some text');
```

The other change I've made is that modalFunc will need to be prefixed by *this* as it exists as part of the same returned object as *validateText*.